# SonarQube exclude whole folder except one file in it

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to set up my `sonar-project.properties` file and faced a little problem.

I want `sonar.exclusions` and `sonar.coverage.exclusions` to exclude one folder except for one file.

```
folder to exclude:
  - folder a
  - folder b
  - file x
  - file y
  - file z
```

**Expected:**
`sonar.exclusions=**/<folder to exclude>/** but not **/<folder to exlude>/<file y>.type`

Comment: Check this out https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.6/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/